# How do I do calculations with data from user input?

Tags: inputfield, user-interface

I'm pretty new to mathematica and I'd like to create a little program that takes user input as variables which it then uses to do some calculations. I have the following code:

```
Clear[numcols, nullbitmap]

    DynamicModule[{numcols, nullbitmap},
 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[numcols], Number, 
    FieldSize -> {15, {1, Infinity}}], 
   Button[Style["Process"], 
    nullbitmap[numcols_] = 2 + ((7 + numcols)/8)]
   }]]

Print[nullbitmap]
```

But this doesn't print the result I and it seems that it doesn't take the 'numcols' as a variable in the calculation.

Comment: There are several problems with your code, Print is immediate instead of triggered from Button, also `nullbitmap[numcols_] = 2 + ((7 + numcols)/8)]` looks at least confusing replaced by `Print[2 + ((7 + numcols)/8)]` should do what you need. I'm encouraging you to go through documentation of `DynamicModule`, `InputField`, `Button`, especially basic examples and applications sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[numcols, nullbitmap]

DynamicModule[{numcols, nullbitmap}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[numcols], Number, 
    FieldSize -> {15, {1, Infinity}}], 
   Button[Style["Process"], nullbitmap = 2 + ((7 + numcols)/8); 
    Print[nullbitmap]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Have fun!